# Group By Expression query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
Select Books.Category, Books.Retail,
Round(Orderitems.Quantity * (Books.Retail - Books.Cost),0) AS Category_Profit
From Books
INNER JOIN Orderitems
ON BOOKS.Retail=ORDERITEMS.Paideach
Group by Books.Category, Books.Retail
```

What I'm trying to do is display the category and the total amount of profit for each category. There are two tables involved

```
Books Table = Category & Retail & Cost
Orderitems Table= Quantity & Paid each
```

So e.g Category has

```
Sports = Football, Basketball
Food = Chicken, Beef
```

The result will show the retail prices of Football + Basketball in one category and in another row it will show Chicken + Beef as one

The relation between the two tables is that retail = paid each
Also trying to round off the value of Category_Profit to the nearest full value.

I'm getting an error of ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression on line 2

Comment: I don't understand everything you are describing, but it sounds like you just forgot to use the `sum` function. (e.g.: `sum(...) as category_profit`)

Comment: so basically the output currently displays 

(Category,retail, category_profit) --- (Sports, 50, 17)--- (Sports,29,8)

I want to I guess "merge" these two sports categories and display it as one so it will show (Sports, 79, 25)

Comment: This looks queer. `retail` is an amount and you join the tables on the amount? I.e all books with `retail` = 50 get joined with all orderitems with `paideach` = 50? This can't be desired, can it? Apart from that: If you want one result row per category, then group by category. Why do you group by category + retail? That doesn't give you one result row per category, but one per category-retail combination.Then you say you want totals, so where is the addition in your query? You'd sum over multiple records with `SUM`.

Comment: It's pretty obvious your real-life case is more complicated than what you have shown. It is OK (actually, desired and encouraged) that you simplify your question as much as possible, but you simplified it too much. I edited your post to add "Cost" to your description of the "Books Table" because obviously in your query you have that column. But there must be more, and I didn't want to make things up for you. The Books table can't be just Category and Retail (and Cost) - it may have book title, book author (both irrelevant), book id (absolutely relevant and needed to solve the problem).

Comment: (continued) - The Orders table must have some identification of the book sold, not just Quantity and PaidEach. It must have book id (or, if the database is poorly written, it may show book title used as id). Please edit your post to add this information. Also: you show "Football, Baseball" - in the Books Table, is a book shown as "Football" or as "Sports" under category? (Or perhaps both, in a poorly designed database.) If it's "Football" - and there is a third table, Categories, that shows that "Football" is in the "Sports" category, you need to join on that table too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only need to group by `category`, not `retail`.  But then you need to use the `sum` aggregate function for the other values:

```
Select Books.Category, 
       sum(Books.Retail),
       Round(sum(Orderitems.Quantity * (Books.Retail - Books.Cost)),0) AS Category_Profit
  From Books
 INNER JOIN Orderitems
    ON BOOKS.Retail=ORDERITEMS.Paideach
 Group by Books.Category
```

Comment: I was about to give the same answer, when I suddenly noticed that the OP joins the tables on the amount. So the question is answered, but the query is most likely semantically incorrect.

Comment: @Thorsten: You are absolutely right. OP: you may want to double check your join condition.

Comment: `sum(Books.Retail)` doesn't belong in the `select` clause, any more than `Books.Retail` does. Obviously `Books.Retail` is the retail price of an individual book; it has no meaning in a query that computes total profit generated by category.